# How to create javascript paganation using my datatables with filter

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me add a simple pagination script on my current script right now. 
I need to have my datatables to be on pages 5 per page perhaps which also can access the current filter that I created. Please help me on this one.

**This is my filter script**

```
    function filterBar() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is my datatable**

Filter:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 60%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 40%;">Country</th>
            <th style="width: 30%;">Age</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>North/South</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paris specialites</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try a plugin from [DataTable](http://datatables.net).
It will handle your pagination very nicely.

Comment: sorry, I'm very new here and I cant use any plugin, just a simple js for pagination will be a great help

Comment: Dont listen to this guy, yes datatable will handle the pagination if you have few records but trust me when you are fetching thousands of records that last thing is you want is to render the pagination front end. Do the pagination server side.

Comment: @RajaKhoury can you help me on this one. Can you add the pagination JS to my code, I badly need help.

Comment: If you use datatables.net plugin then it's so simple, They've instructed very nicely.

Comment: @John Look the documentation for the `dom` options there you can set where to render the table, filters, pagination also for filtering the table you can use the `search()` api .
https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom & https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()